# How to configure Mocha with VS Code

Tags: testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

Hi I'm trying to setup Mocka and Chai frameworks with Visual Studio Code but I'm getting error when I'm trying to run mocha unit test saying:

Attribute 'program' does not exist ('C:\Users...node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha')

http://prikachi.com/images/321/9672321w.png

It must be something from the settings.
This is the JSON config file of VS Code launch.json

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Mocha Tests",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
        "args": [
            "-u",
            "bdd",
            "--timeout",
            "999999",
            "--colors",
            "${file}"
        ],
        "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
    },
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${file}"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Publish the error here as text.  Pictures of code are not useful.

Comment: Attribute 'program' does not exist ('C:\Users...node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha')